# Why don't I get suggestions with a multi-term partial query?

Tags: marklogic

I have an `authors` range constraint based on a path range index. The values are strings, with the index using the "http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1" collation.

When I call `cts.values` on that pathReference, I see values like "Smith, A.", "Smith, B.", "Smith, A. B." etc. I can also use the `/v1/suggest` endpoint with a `partial-q` parameter of "Authors:Smith" and I'll get back all the expected values.

However, if I want to narrow it down more by including a first initial in the `partial-q`, I figure need to enclose the value in quotes (`partial-q=Authors:"Smith, A"`), but if I do that I get no results (successful query; no values). In fact, as soon as I add quotes (`partial-q=Authors:"Smith"`) I stop getting results.

Does `/v1/suggest` support this kind of query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree it is not very obvious, but you need to drop the closing quote, so that MarkLogic knows the string value is not finished yet. So you send: `partial-q=Authors:"Smith, A`

HTH!

Comment: I don't think I would ever have thought of that. Thanks, Geert!

Comment: Good to know, and works, but for me adding that open quote is adding the same additional open quote to the results.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it should return results that have either no quotes, or a matching pair of quotes. It is easy to suppress that initial quote client-side if it doesn't though..